# Azure - backup app on vm before delivering new changes

Tags: azure, deployment, backup, azure-virtual-machine

I have several .NET applications that are hosted In Azure on virtual machines IIS. I want to automate deployment process directly from my machine or visual studio without using Azure portal because we are doing several deliveries each day. The biggest challenge for me now is to do backup before deployment. So I need to backup specific folder on VM remotely. Could anyone tell me how I can do it?
Are there any best practices for automation delivery from visual studio to Azure VM? Backup of app is required.

Answer (score 1):

First, I'm assuming that you would like to back up some specific folders in your VM to an Azure Blobs or Azure Files storage. There are two parts you'd need to complete your continuous deployment:

1. Automate backing up some folders in your virtual machine.
2. Integrate task #1 into a CICD (Continuous Integration Continuous Deployment) tool, which I'd suggest VSTS (Visual Studio Team Services) for your beginning.

**Approach #1**

You can expose Windows Remote Management (WinRM) endpoint publicly and use PowerShell to perform a folder backup task. You will also need to invoke some scripts to write/copy your backup to Azure Blobs Storage. Your script must be authenticated silently so you don't need to key in Azure subscription admin or VM admin.

Once you have a PowerShell script, you can invoke this PowerShell by creating a new [PowerShell task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/tasks/utility/powershell) in your [Build or Release definition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/actions/ci-cd-part-1). I'd suggest to define in Release definition.

**Approach #2**

It's more Cloud native and you don't have to expose WMI of your virtual machine which would lead to security threat. Instead, you utilize Azure Automation Worker to automate the entirely backup & copy to another Azure services (Blobs, Files, another backup/file server virtual machine..). In your run book, you need to use PowerShell DSC (Desired State Configuration) to [interact with resources inside your virtual machine](https://thuansoldier.net/?p=6461).

In VSTS, you have two ways to start your runbook

1. Invoke runbook's webhook: you can [create a webhook for your runbook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-webhooks) and call this webhook by creating a [Http Task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/tasks/utility/http-rest-api)
2. Start runbook by PowerShell: similar to the approach #1, just create PowerShell task then use `Start-AzureAutomationRunbook` cmdlet with sample [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Azure/Start-AzureAutomationRunbook?view=azuresmps-4.0.0).
3. Build an [ARM template for your Runbook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.automation/automationaccounts/runbooks) then define in Build definition. [Here](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/canitpro/2016/02/08/devops-basics-deploying-azure-resource-manager-templates-with-visual-studio-team-services/) is the sample reference to deploy an ARM template in VSTS,

The reason I have to give several references because you might not have familiarity with CICD and DevOps concept, as well as some useful tools in Azure and VSTS which supports your continuous deployment. There are some awesome CICD solutions in the market you should also explore, such as Chef, Ansible, Puppet. They support CICD very well. Below are some references to get started with DevOps on Azure:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/deploy-azure/
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-dsc-overview
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/apps/cd/azure/azure-devops-project-aspnetcore

Comment: Hi,

thank you for your answer, but, unfortunately, we are not using VSTS now. Currently we are working with SVN and doing deployments to azure vm manually via login with rdp. I have investigated a lot and now I can make a conclusion that migration to VSTS will bring us benefits and I am going to start this process right away. Probably your solution will work for me but I am going to get back with a result when I try it.

Comment: @Roman VSTS is not necessary. In fact you can have complex PowerShell script with WMI exposure to perform the entire task. VSTS is just a good tool providing friendly and more added value for CICD.